# Blazor WASM - Identity Server 4 - Role Claim not being populated

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, .net-6.0, claims

Could anyone share some light on my issue as I've become quite stumped?

My set up,
Blazor Wasm .Net 6, Identity Server 4, Standard AddOidcAuthentication in the client.
[image]

When viewing my claims page, it doesn't show any values from Role.

```cs
    <h3>ClaimsPrincipal Data</h3>

    <button @onclick="GetClaimsPrincipalData">Get ClaimsPrincipal Data</button>

    <p>@authMessage</p>

    @if (claims.Count() > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                <li>@claim.Type: @claim.Value</li>
            }
        </ul>
    }

    <p>@surnameMessage</p>

    @code {
        private string authMessage;
        private string surnameMessage;
        private IEnumerable<Claim> claims = Enumerable.Empty<Claim>();

        private async Task GetClaimsPrincipalData()
        {
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;

            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
                claims = user.Claims;
                surnameMessage =
                $"Surname: {user.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value}";
            }
            else
            {
                authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Output from above....
[image]

If I check the bearer token, it clearly has the roles
[image]

If anyone has experienced this before or knows how to resolve it, I'd really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: It looks like the Role is in a comma separated string. This does not work for role detection. You have to transform the string into separate role claims. There are posts already on here showing how to do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity does your code work if the user only has one role?

Comment: Hi Brian, yes I have also seen this about the comma-separated roles, I went down the track of trying to deal with this as my first course of action but it turned out. I didn't have the correct configuration of the identity resource. Thanks for taking the time to assist me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, Brain you were right, I also needed to handle the array of roles. 

For anyone else...  see my answer below with the screenshots

Answer (score 2):

thanks for taking the time to help out. It's always nice to know there are fellow coders out there that have your back.

After a screen sharing session with a friend, we worked it out, the Auth_token contained the roles, and the identity_token didn't.

For anyone else in the future that may come across this problem of not knowing, screenshots are below.

I am using the great Skoruba admin UI to manage my identity server.
The problem was that the role was not assigned to the identity resource.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once this is done, everything works as expected.

I also needed to handle the array of roles this was done by the following in program.cs

```cs
 builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("Identity", options.ProviderOptions);
                options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
            })
            .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<ArrayClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>>()
```

Then a new class containing

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.Internal;
public class ArrayClaimsPrincipalFactory<TAccount> : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<TAccount> where TAccount : RemoteUserAccount
    {
        public ArrayClaimsPrincipalFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
        : base(accessor)
        { }


        // when a user belongs to multiple roles, IS4 returns a single claim with a serialised array of values
        // this class improves the original factory by deserializing the claims in the correct way
        public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(TAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
        {
            var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

            var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;

            if (account != null)
            {
                foreach (var kvp in account.AdditionalProperties)
                {
                    var name = kvp.Key;
                    var value = kvp.Value;
                    if (value != null &&
                        (value is JsonElement element && element.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array))
                    {
                        claimsIdentity.RemoveClaim(claimsIdentity.FindFirst(kvp.Key));

                        var claims = element.EnumerateArray()
                            .Select(x => new Claim(kvp.Key, x.ToString()));

                        claimsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
                    }
                }
            }

            return user;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, in .NET only a few standard claims are mapped into the user object.

To get the rest, you need to add this code:

```
AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("employment_start", "employment_start");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("seniority", "seniority");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("contractor", "contractor");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("employee", "employee");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("management", "management");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);

    //optionally, add this to tell ASP.NET which claim is the name and role claim.
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
    };
    ....
}
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)